# How should I play video in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, video

My machine is unable to play any video format. Error is:

```
Videos requires to install plugins to play files of the followings 
types:MPEG-1 Layer 3(MP3) decoders, MPEG-4 Video decoder.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package.

Install it using

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: Please provide me the exact link from where I can able to download and install.

Comment: Is above command is not installing the package for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and paste following command.

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: Can you please give me the exact link

Comment: Asking for [sudo] password for arghya:

Comment: Give the password that you used to log in.